# Function multiple cases horizontal spaces

Tags: cases

I have a multi cases function which almost exceeds the page bounds because of long definition of the second case.

How would you suggest me doing this otherwise to make the document look more beautiful?

```
For any other bag $b$ and for any of its subsets $U$ ($C(b) =$ children of $b$):
\[
    M[b, U] = 
    \begin{cases}
    \hfill \infty   \hfill & \text{ if $U$ is not a VC for $G(V_b)$ } \\
    \hfill \sum_{b' \in C(b)} \min\{M[b', U'] | U' \in P(b') \wedge U \cap b' \subseteq U' \} - |U \cap U'|         \hfill & \text{ else }
    \end{cases}
\]
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Such long formulas should be avoided in summations like that: they are too hard to read, besides occupying too much space.

It's better to reduce the big formula using a definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

For any other bag $b$ and for any of its subsets $U$ ($C(b) =$ children of $b$):
\[
M[b, U] =
\begin{dcases*}
  \; \infty & if $U$ is not a VC for $G(V_b)$ \\
  \sum_{b' \in C(b)} \mu(b') - |U \cap U'| & else
\end{dcases*}
\]
where
\[
\mu(b')=\min\{M[b', U'] \mid U' \in P(b') \wedge U \cap b' \subseteq U' \}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]